# c++ declaring a variable when passing it into a function

Tags: c++, class, variables

I come from a world of c# were doing something like this is allowed. When I try it in c++ I get no compiler errors but I am not convinced it is actually working.

So to more experienced people are you allowed to do something like this:

```
Entity->SetPosition(Vector2(200, 400));
```

As In Vector2 is a class and the parameter for set position requires a vector? Is this allowed or do I need to pre-initialize the variable like so:

```
Vector2 aVector(200, 400);
Entity->SetPosition(aVector);
```

Thanks
David

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Entity->SetPosition(Vector2(200, 400));
```

is fine *(and preferable)* if you've defined `SetPosition` as one of the following:

```
void SetPosition(Vector2 const & v); //Okay : const reference
void SetPosition(Vector2  v);        //okay : value
```

that is, `SetPosition` accepts the argument as `const` *reference*, Or simply as *value*.

This wouldn't work though:

```
void SetPosition(Vector2 & v);  //not okay : non-const reference
```

--

In C++11, you could just write this *(provided you have implemented `Vector2` to [enable this behavior](http://ideone.com/tbQZF))*:

```
Entity->SetPosition({200, 400});
```

Thanks to @Simon for pointing this out.

Comment: I believe in c++11 you'll be able to do `Entity->SetPosition({200, 400});` provided this doesn't create ambiguity.

Comment: I take that back. It doesn't work. I may have to read some more on c++11.

Comment: @Simon: It should work if you implement `Vector2` to enable that behavior. See this demo : http://ideone.com/tbQZF

Answer (score 1):

In general yes this is just fine.  In general a Set style API in C++ will take either a value or a `const &` to the value being set.  In both of those cases it's fine to use an inline expression.

```
class Entity { 
public:
  void SetPosition(const Vector2& value) { ... }
  void SetPosition(Vector2 value) { ... } 
};
```

It isn't legal though in the case where `SetPosition` takes just a reference

```
void SetPosition(Vector2& value) { ... }
```

This isn't the common idiom for setters though

Comment: What would be more recommended then may I ask?

Comment: @DavidC when possible I use the `const &` version.  It's **generally** more efficient to pass by reference and `const &` prevents the receiver from modifying the value. With some objects though, particularly those which aren't `const` correct, it may be necessary to have it accept a simple value

Comment: @JaredPar When passing a temporary, as in this example, there's probably no difference between pass by value and pass by reference.  If the called function actually needs a copy of its own (that it will modify), then pass by reference may be more expensive. For various historical reasons, the convention of passing class types by const reference, and other types by value, seems to be ubiquitous, to the point where anything else draws attention to itself.  But with modern compilers, I wouldn't read too much into it with regards to performance.